# JBL Go 3 speaker not connecting to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I acquired a new laptop some months ago and have happily been using Ubuntu 20.04 but I've encountered a recent problem... My JBL Go 3 speaker is not connecting to the computer through bluetooth. I've read that I could disconnect the Wifi and it did help but now it doesn't connect at all. And when it does it works fine for a while but all of a sudden the sounds begin to be all choppy (as if the connection was not good) even when the speaker is right in front of the computer. If I disconnect the speaker there's not way it will connect again.

Can anyone guide me on what's actually going on and if there's a way to fix this? The speaker is not the problem at all, it connects fine to my cellphone and my work computer. Also other devices (like my phone) connect to the computer fine as well.

Thanks in advance for your help! Let me know what you need from me.

Comment: Anyone? I'm desperate now it's not connecting to any device at all!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing happen with a JBL GO2. I finally solved it by installing

```
sudo apt install rfkill
```

and using the command

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
```

Once rfkill is installed you will be able to see if a device is locked with the command

```
sudo rfkill list
```

If you see that a bluetooth device is locked enter the locked number at the end of the following command e.g.

```
sudo rfkill unblock 7
```

in case number 7 is locked.